# No loss decay while learning Neural Network for X-OR operation in torch

Tags: neural-network, torch

I have implemented a simple 1 hidden layer feed forward neural network in torch to learn X-OR operation. Below is my code:

```
require 'torch'
require 'nn'

m = nn.Sequential()
m:add(nn.Linear(2,2))
m:add(nn.Linear(2,1))
m:add(nn.Sigmoid())

torch.manualSeed(1)

m.modules[1].weights = torch.rand(2,2)
m.modules[2].weights = torch.rand(2,1)

--print(parax_m)

criterion = nn.BCECriterion()

inputs = torch.Tensor(4,2)
inputs[1][1] = 0
inputs[1][2] = 0

inputs[2][1] = 0
inputs[2][2] = 1

inputs[3][1] = 1
inputs[3][2] = 0

inputs[4][1] = 1
inputs[4][2] = 1

targets = torch.Tensor(4,1)
targets[1][1] = 0
targets[2][1] = 1
targets[3][1] = 1
targets[4][1] = 0

function trainEpoch(m,criterion,inputs,targets)
    for i=1,inputs:size(1) do
        local input = inputs[i]
        local target = targets[i]
        local output = m:forward(input)
        --print(output)
        local loss = criterion:forward(output,target)
        print(loss)

            -- backward
        local gradOutput = criterion:backward(output,target)
        m:zeroGradParameters()
        local gradInput = m:backward(input,gradOutput)
        --update
        --module:updateGradParameters(0.9) -- momentum (require dpnn)
        m:updateParameters(0.01) -- W = W -0.1*dL/dW
    end
end

for i=1,10000 do
    trainEpoch(m,criterion,inputs,targets)
end

-- prediciton
testinput = torch.Tensor(4,2)
testinput[1][1] = 0
testinput[1][2] = 0

testinput[2][1] = 0
testinput[2][2] = 1

testinput[3][1] = 1
testinput[3][2] = 0

testinput[4][1] = 1
testinput[4][2] = 1

for i=1,testinput:size(1) do
    local output = m:forward(testinput[i])
    print(output)
end
```

When I run the above code, there is no decay in loss(almost same in all iterations) so it does not predict the correct output. Can anyone help me to find the mistakes what I am doing wrong here?

I have also tried with different manual seed value, different initialisation of weights but still loss remains same in all iterations.

Comment: Am I right in thinking your learning rate is 0.1? I'm looking at this line: `m:updateParameters(0.01) -- W = W -0.1*dL/dW`. A learning rate that high in SGD is likely going to cause the signal to jump back and forth across the error surface instead of descending into a local minimum. Try a lower learning rate, and perhaps a learning rate decay schedule.

Comment: @StatsSorceress Thanks for the reply... Learning rate is 0.01. 0.1 is only in comment. I have also tried with 0.001. No improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the error in my Network.
1. I haven't added the non-linear layer after the first linear layer.
2. No randomisation while running stochastic gradient descent.

By updating these two things, now it is working fine.
Updated Code:

```
require 'torch'
require 'nn'

m = nn.Sequential()
m:add(nn.Linear(2,2))
m:add(nn.Tanh())
m:add(nn.Linear(2,1))
m:add(nn.Sigmoid())

--print(parax_m)

criterion = nn.BCECriterion()

inputs = torch.Tensor(4,2)
inputs[1][1] = 0
inputs[1][2] = 0

inputs[2][1] = 0
inputs[2][2] = 1

inputs[3][1] = 1
inputs[3][2] = 0

inputs[4][1] = 1
inputs[4][2] = 1

targets = torch.Tensor(4,1)
targets[1][1] = 0
targets[2][1] = 1
targets[3][1] = 1
targets[4][1] = 0

function trainEpoch(m,criterion,inputs,targets)
    for i=1,inputs:size(1) do
        local idx = math.random(1,4)
        local input = inputs[idx]
        local target = targets[idx]
        local output = m:forward(input)
        --print(output)
        local loss = criterion:forward(output,target)
        print(loss)

            -- backward
        local gradOutput = criterion:backward(output,target)
        m:zeroGradParameters()
        local gradInput = m:backward(input,gradOutput)
        --update
        --module:updateGradParameters(0.9) -- momentum (require dpnn)
        m:updateParameters(0.01) -- W = W -0.1*dL/dW
    end
end

for i=1,10000 do
    trainEpoch(m,criterion,inputs,targets)
end

-- prediciton
testinput = torch.Tensor(4,2)
testinput[1][1] = 0
testinput[1][2] = 0

testinput[2][1] = 0
testinput[2][2] = 1

testinput[3][1] = 1
testinput[3][2] = 0

testinput[4][1] = 1
testinput[4][2] = 1

for i=1,testinput:size(1) do
    local output = m:forward(testinput[i])
    print(output)
end
```